# Proving Linear Time Temporal Logic formula □ ◊ f ⇔ ◊ □ f

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, linear-temporal-logic, temporal-logic

I am new to this topic, [Linear Time Temporal Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) and I am trying to prove this equivalence --

$\Box\Diamond f \Leftrightarrow \Diamond\Box f$

This is my take --

Basic definitions:

$(\sigma, j) \models \Box f: \forall k \, [(k \ge j) \Rightarrow ((\sigma, k) \models f)]$

$(\sigma, j) \models \Diamond f: \exists k \, [(k \ge j) \Rightarrow ((\sigma, k) \models f)]$

Here, $(\sigma, j) \models f$ means $\sigma$ satisfies $f$ at $\sigma(j)$, for more details about this syntax, please see [here](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~artale/FM/slide3.pdf).

Now the LHS:

$\begin{eqnarray}
(\sigma, j) \models \Box \Diamond f & : & \forall k \, [(k \ge j) \Rightarrow ((\sigma, k) \models \Diamond f)]\\
& \equiv & \forall k \, [(k \ge j) \Rightarrow [\exists p \, [(p \ge k) \Rightarrow ((\sigma, p) \models f)]]]\\
& \equiv & \forall k \, [(k<j) \vee [\exists p \, [(p<k) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)]]]\\ 
& \equiv & \forall k \, \exists p \, [(k<j) \vee (p<k) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)]\\ 
& \equiv & \forall k \, \exists p \, [(p<k<j) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)]\\
\end{eqnarray}
$

Again, the RHS:

$\begin{eqnarray}
(\sigma, j) \models \Diamond \Box f & : & \exists k \, [(k \ge j) \Rightarrow ((\sigma, k) \models \Box f)]\\
& \equiv & \exists k \, [(k \ge j) \Rightarrow [\forall p \, [(p \ge k) \Rightarrow ((\sigma, p) \models f)]]]\\
& \equiv & \exists k \, [(k<j) \vee [\forall p \, [(p<k) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)]]]\\ 
& \equiv & \exists k \, \forall p \, [(p<k<j) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)]\\ 
\end{eqnarray}
$

Now if we look at the last line of the both sides, the statement

$\forall k \, \exists p \, [(p<k<j) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)] \equiv \exists k \, \forall p \, [(p<k<j) \vee ((\sigma,p) \models f)]$

needs to be true to complete the proof, however intuitively, this is not true.

What I am missing? How do I proceed? Any idea?

Comment: Are you confident that the equivalence holds?

Comment: no, actually they don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not missing anything. These expressions are indeed not equivalent.
Assume $f$ in your case is an atomic proposition. Then the computation:
$f,\neg f,(f,\neg f)^\omega$ satisfies $□◊f$, but not $\Diamond \square f$.

Intuitively, $\Diamond \square f$ means "After a finite prefix, there is always $f$", while $\square \Diamond f$ means: "There are infinitely many $f$s".

By the way, you have some mistake in your semantics. It should be:
$(\sigma,j)\models \Diamond f$: $\exists k[k\ge j\wedge (\sigma,k)\models f]$.

Comment: you are right, btw, what does it mean by $(f, \neg f)^{\omega}$ ?

Comment: It means that the path is of the form $f,\neg f,f,\neg f,...$ and continues like that infinitely.

Comment: @ramgorur $\_^{\omega}$ is like the Kleene star but with "infinitely many repetitions", not "arbitrarily many repetitions". See [$\omega$-regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-regular_language).